# Can't get Rails 3 ActionMailer to accept an attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, email-attachments

I am migrating an Rails 2.3.14 application to Rails 3.0. In it, a mailer sends a message with an attachment. Using the code below, this worked without issue in 2.3.x.

```
def notification(material, recipient, path_to_file)  
  enctype = "base64"

  @recipients  = recipient.email
  @from        = material.person.email
  @reply_to    = material.person.email
  @subject     = "New or updated materials: " + material.name
  @sent_on     = Time.now
  @content_type = "multipart/mixed"
  @headers['sender'] = material.person.email

  part    :content_type => "text/plain", 
          :body => render_message('notification', 
          :material => material, 
          :url =>  material.full_url_to_material)

  attachment  :content_type => "application" + "/" + material.file_type, 
              :body => File.read(path_to_file), 
              :filename => File.basename(material.file),
              :transfer_encoding => enctype, 
              :charset => "utf-8" if !!material.send_as_attachment

end
```

Reading through the Rails 3.0 [ActionMailer instructions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html), I have modified the method to the following:

```
  def notification(material, recipient, path_to_file)
    @material = material
    @url = material.full_url_to_material
    attachments[material.file_file_name] = File.open(path_to_file, 'rb'){|f| f.read} if material.send_as_attachment?
    headers['sender'] = material.person.email
    mail(:to => recipient.email,
         :subject => "New or updated materials: " + material.name,
         :reply_to => material.person.email, 
         :from =>  material.person.email)
  end
```

MaterialMailer#notification is called when a material is created. I have the following spec to test this:

```
  it "will include the materials as an attachement with the the send_as_attachment field is set to 1" do
    it = Material.create(@materials_hash.merge(:send_notification => "1", :send_as_attachment => "1"))
    email =  ActionMailer::Base.deliveries[0] 
    email.body.should =~ Regexp.new("Name of the posted material: " + it.name )
    email.has_attachments?.should be_true
  end
```

As I mentioned, this worked fine in 2.3. Now, if I set the send_as_attachment flag to one, I get the following error, referencing the email.body.should line:

```
  1) Material will include the materials as an attachement with the the send_as_attachment field is set to 1
     Failure/Error: email.body.should =~ Regexp.new("Name of the posted material: " + it.name )
       expected: /Name of the posted material: My material/
            got:  (using =~)
       Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1 @@
       -/Name of the posted material: My material/
```

If I change the spec and set the send_as_attachment to 0, I get the following error, referencing the has_attachments? line:

1) Material will include the materials as an attachement with the the send_as_attachment field is set to 1
     Failure/Error: email.has_attachments?.should be_true
       expected false to be true

So including the attachment is somehow breaking the email.

I have tried other methods for attaching the material:

```
  attachments[material.file_file_name] =  {:mime_type => "application" + "/" + material.file_content_type, 
              :content => File.read(material.file.path),  
              :charset => "utf-8"}
```

I have tried hardcoding the file paths to known files. But no luck.

Any where else I should look?

Comment: Ironies of Ironies, after finishing this opus, I just figured it out. I need to look at the first part of the email for the body.

Comment: mail.parts[0].body.should =~ Regexp.new("Name of the posted material: " + it.name )

Comment: You should post your answer of how you got it so other people who run into this can find it :}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Christopher's suggestion, here is the mailer and spec code that I used to get it to work:

```
  def notification(material, recipient, path_to_file)
    @material = material
    @url = material.full_url_to_material
    attachments[material.file_file_name] = File.open(material.file.path, 'rb'){|f| f.read} if material.send_as_attachment?
    headers['sender'] = material.person.email
    mail(:to => recipient.email,
         :subject => message_subject("New or updated materials: " + material.name),
         :reply_to => material.person.email, 
         :from =>  material.person.email)
  end

  it "will include the materials as an attachment with the the send_as_attachment field is set to 1" do
    it = Material.create(@materials_hash.merge(:send_notification => "1", :send_as_attachment => "1"))
    Delayed::Worker.new(:quiet => true).work_off
    email =  ActionMailer::Base.deliveries[0] 
    email.parts.each.select{ |email| email.body =~ Regexp.new("Name of the posted material: " + it.name )}.should_not be_empty
    email.has_attachments?.should be_true
  end
```

In the spec, I had to check the body of each of the parts of the email, as it was not consistent on whether the attachment was the first or second part.